# Scroll to given jCarousel slide on page load

Tags: jquery, hash, custom-controls, history, jcarousel

Hello stackoverflow contributors! I have this script that gets the starting position of my jCarousel through the browser URL's hash. Something like **text.html#2**.

What am trying to achieve is make jCarousel scroll to the given position on page load. However my code below seems to work only if I bind it to clicks - it does not respond to on page load requests.

**Initialize jCarousel**

```
jQuery('#body_list').jcarousel({
        scroll: 1,
        initCallback: bodylist_initCallback
});
```

**Callback function**

```
function bodylist_initCallback(carousel) {
        $(window).load(function () {
            if(window.location.hash) {
                var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1); 
                carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(hash));
            }
        });
});
```

**Alternative scroll call**
The following lines works except in Safari

```
if(window.location.hash) {
        var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1); 
        jQuery('#body_list').jcarousel('scroll', hash);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the `start` option when you initialize the jCarousel:

```
var hash = 1; // Default start index if none is specified in URL
if (window.location.hash) {
    hash = parseInt(window.location.hash.slice(1));
}
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    start: hash,
    scroll: 1
});
```

**Update**

If you want to see the scrolling animation when you load the page, try setting a timeout in the `initCallback` option for jCarousel:

```
jQuery("#mycarousel").jcarousel({
    initCallback: function(carousel) {
        if (window.location.hash) {
            var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
            setTimeout(function() {
                carousel.scroll(parseInt(hash, 10));
            }, 500);
        }
    }
});
```

Seems to work in FF/Chrome.  I'm on Ubuntu so I can't try it on IE or Safari.

Comment: hmm 'start' sets the start to the given position without scrolling/ sliding the panel to it.

Comment: @James: Oh, sorry, I didn't catch that in the OP.  I'll update my answer.